# Which JavaFX CSS property is this?

Tags: css, javafx

[image: Weird insets]

I have this table view in JavaFX, I wanted to put a grey border around the selected row so I added this css rule:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-border-color: grey;
}
```

However I seem to have lost some padding along the way and the row appears shifted to the left. (See image)

Is there some padding property I should be adding in? I'm a total CSS newbie which doesn't help when scanning through the caspian.css file :/

Comment: EDIT for more info:
The columns are being coloured in the java CellFactory with TableCell.setBackground(..) so AFAIK that's not a CSS rule.
The only other rule I'm applying in code is:

                 setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `TableRow` doesn't apply a border, so the different  `TableCell` elements within the row take the whole space of the row.

With your css:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-border-color: grey;
}
```

you are applying a border to the row, with a default width of 1 pixel. When the row is selected, in order not to disturb the rest of the rows, to allocate this border, each cell has to take into account a decrease of 1 pixel in *every* of its four sides.

This means that each cell is 2 pixels shorter and *narrower*, and therefore there is a shift to the left when they are rendered, as can be seen in the posted screenshot.

The cell size change can easily checked with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/).

While this is probably a bug (as with row selection only the height should be modified for all the cells, applying only 1 pixel in the left of the first cell and 1 pixel to the right of the last cell), there is an easy solution, if you have a look at how modena.css is applied.

Instead of using border colors, cells and rows use two background colors with some shift between them to create a border effect.

```
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

For every row, the color underneath is defined by `-fx-table-cell-border-color`, and with a one pixel shift in the bottom, the main color on top is defined by `-fx-background`. When the table row is selected, the insets shift to `-fx-background-insets: 0, 1`. Note that also `-fx-table-cell-border-color` is used as a "border" color for each cell.

The solution to apply a custom grey border color, without modifying the cells within the row, is:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: grey, -fx-background;
}
```

That way, you still keep the top background color for the row and the border color for the cells.